# Search for different values in subsequent rows within a DataFrame -

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I am trying to search if a value of a row is greater in the following values of another column (not in the whole column).

I am using a pandas DataFrame in Python. No code has worked well yet.

Ex:
If Value1 > Value2(T+n)

```
Date        Value1  Value2
2021-02-18  11,07   10,82
2021-02-19  10,36   10,05
2021-02-22  7,88    7,94
2021-02-23  8,45    8,47
2021-02-24  8,64    8,72
2021-02-25  8,93    8,27
2021-02-26  8,32    7,93
2021-03-01  7,95    7,81
2021-03-02  7,52    7,74
2021-03-03  7,38    7,43
2021-03-04  7,77    7,63
```

I need this output to be displayed:

```
Date        Value1  Value2  Result
2021-02-18  11,07   10,82   True
2021-02-19  10,36   10,05   True
2021-02-22  7,88    7,94    False
2021-02-23  8,45    8,47    False
2021-02-24  8,64    8,72    True
2021-02-25  8,93    8,27    True
2021-02-26  8,32    7,93    True
2021-03-01  7,95    7,81    True
2021-03-02  7,52    7,74    False
2021-03-03  7,38    7,43    False
2021-03-04  7,77    7,63    -
```

Comment: `df['Result'] = df['Value1'] > df['Value2'].shift()`? Make sure you are comparing numbers, not strings.

Comment: @QuangHoang I have already tried that. However, note that I am trying to compare Valeu1 with ALL the following values of Value2 column. A should make some iteration for the ".shift()", but I don't know how.

Comment: `df.assign(Result=df['Value1'].gt(df['Value2'].shift(-1)))`?